# Python project and package directories layout

Tags: python, package

I created a project in python, and I'm curious about how packages work in python.

Here is my directory layout:

```
top-level dir
  \ tests
    __init__.py 
  \ examples
    __init__.py
    example.py
module.py
```

How would I go about including module.py in my example.py module.  I know I could set PYTHONPATH to the top-level directory, but that doesn't seem like a good solution.  This is how pydev gets around this problem, but I'd like a solution that didn't require updating environment variables.

I could put something at the top of the example.py to update sys.path like this:

```
from os import path
import sys

sys.path.append( path.dirname(path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))) )
```

I don't think this is an appropriate solution either.

I feel like I'm missing some basic part of python packages.  I'm testing this on python 2.6.  If any further clarification is needed, please let me know.

Comment: http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/39794.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python packages are very simple: a package is any directory under any entry in sys.path that has an `__init__.py` file.  However, a module is only considered to be IN a package if it is imported via a relative import such as `import package.module` or `from package import module`.  Note that this means that in general, someone *must* set up sys.path to contain the directories above any package you want to be importable, whether via `PYTHONPATH` or otherwise.

The primary wrinkle is that main modules (those run directly from the command line) are always `__main__` no matter their location.  They therefore have to do absolute imports, and either rely on PYTHONPATH being set up, or munge sys.path themselves.

In your case,  I'd recommend either having a small Python script that runs your examples after setting up the correct path.  Say you put it in the top level directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os.path

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
example = __import__("examples", globals(), locals(), sys.argv[1])
```

Then your example can do "import module".

Alternately, if `module.py` is meant to also be in a package, add the PARENT of your "top level directory" to sys.path and then use the `from .. import module` syntax in your example modules.  Also, change the first parameter to the `__import__` in the wrapper to "tldname.examples" where tldname is the name of your top-level directory.

If you don't want to rely on an "example runner" module, each example needs sys.path boilerplate, or you need a PYTHONPATH setting.  Sorry.

Comment: Brilliant. The main module being treated specially, without including any other modules was the hint that allowed me to nail this in a portable, nice way. In the main method now, we consistently add our local projects' top directory to the sys.path, and everything else works exactly as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references

```
from .. import module
```

Comment: Upon trying that, I got the following error: ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package.  I have a `__init__.py` in the examples directory and the parent directory.

Comment: If you're not working in a package, then yes, you should be setting PYTHONPATH.

Comment: I am working in a package though.  I have the `__init__.py` in both the top-level directory and examples directory.

Comment: Unless your code is running in the context of having been imported as "import examples.example" (or by relative import from another such module in a package), Python does not consider it as running in a package.  If you are running the example directly, you have to set up sys.path and do an absolute import.